# web service in spring getParameter

Tags: java, spring, web-services

I am creating a web service, but I am not getting the value I expect by using `req.getParameter("key")`. **Can you please tell why I am getting values as `null` ?**

Here, instead of getting `"abcd"` as value, I am getting `null`.

The request which I am hitting is:
`http://localhost:8080/api.htm`.
Post fields are:
`username:abcd`

```
@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping(value = {"api"}, method = {RequestMethod.POST})
    public String apiSignUp(HttpServletRequest req) throws JSONException {
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
        Users user;
        try {
            String username = req.getParameter("username");
```

Comment: The correct syntax would be `username=abcd`.

Comment: I think u are trying ajax call. If you are directly calling url then  http://localhost:8080/api.htm?username=abcd but if you are adding data using json then it should be {"username":"abcd"}. Can you provide the code from where you are calling this service?

Comment: I am using as a web-service. and the data I am sending is in post field.

I have just tried to show that I am sending value abcd for key username.
I am not using it as an ajax I am using it as a http post request.

Comment: Nobody can answer your question until you provide calling code.

Comment: Yes , thank you there is no error in this java code. Error was there in curl url not encoded.